# Command to get iis authentication

Tags: iis-7.5

Is there anyway where we can get the authentication methods used in iis using any windows command or powershell command?i have used the below appcmd command but it gives me the entire config of 'Default Web Site',
appcmd list config "default web site"

Answer (score 0):

You have the module **webadministration**. This module contain the **Get-WebConfiguration** cmdlet ([link to documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/get-webconfiguration?view=winserver2012-ps)).

For your requirement, you can run first:

```
Import-Module webadministration
```

And run the following:

```
Get-WebConfiguration -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/*" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\" | foreach {$_.SectionPath}
```

The result:

```
PS C:\Users\vmsilvamolina> Get-WebConfiguration -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/*" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\" |
 foreach {$_.SectionPath}
/system.webServer/security/authentication/digestAuthentication
/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication
/system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
/system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication
/system.webServer/security/authentication/clientCertificateMappingAuthentication
/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication
PS C:\Users\vmsilvamolina>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment I added ho to select a particular site.

```
$site = "MySiteName"
Get-WebConfiguration -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/*" -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\$site" | foreach {$_.SectionPath}
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt repsonse am able to get the total list of authentications ,but if we need to know which anthentication is applied for a particular website do we need to pass the parameter value in "IIS:\path of website "?

Comment: I edited my response adding the selection on particular website.

Comment: the changed comment has worked good, thank you for the assistance .